# single row query returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

i tried the query below and it returned an error "`single-row query returns more than one row`"

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pans) AS NUMBEROFPANS,
       (SELECT name FROM facts, pans WHERE fact_id=pafact_id) AS NAMEOFPANS,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stas) AS NUMBEROFSTAS,
       (SELECT name FROM facts, stas WHERE fact_id=safact_id) AS NAMEOFSTAS,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM zelyc) AS NUMBEROFZELYCS,
       (SELECT name FROM facts, Zelycs WHERE fact_id=zafact_id) AS NAMEOFZELYCS 
FROM DUAL;
```

desired result:

```
Numberofpans    Nameofpans  Numberofstas    Nameofstas
1           jade             1          relate
1           arrow            1          simi
```

i am using oracle

and also pans, stas and zelycs are subclasses of facts table so they all have the same primary key
Is there a different way to write this query?

Comment: What database are you using?  The use of `dual` would suggest Oracle.  And, can you provide sample data and desired results?  A non-working query often doesn't do a great job of conveying what someone wants.

Comment: i am using oracle, and i want the result  to be:

Comment: Without Knowledge of the data in your Database there is no real way to help you. You might Want to Start to issue the queries involved One by one checking how many Results each one produces.

Comment: @Geily . . . Don't put the desired results in a comment.  Edit the question and add them there.

Comment: Numberofpans Nameofpans Numberofstas Nameofstas
1            jade           1         relate
1            arrow      1         simi
i am using oracle

Comment: You could check if any of these subqueries returns more than one row, which would cause the error: SELECT name FROM facts, pans WHERE fact_id=pafact_id; SELECT name FROM facts, stas WHERE fact_id=safact_id; SELECT name FROM facts, Zelycs WHERE fact_id=zafact_id;

Comment: @GEILY The desired output has repeating columns. Could you please double-check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't very clear what you were trying to do in your post.  I think, considering your other answer / comments on other answers, here might be what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT
   Count(p.pafact_id) as PanCount,
   p.name as Pan,
   Count(s.safact_id) as StasCount,
   s.name as Stas,
   Count(z.zafact_id) as ZelycsCount,
   z.name as Zelyc
FROM
   facts f

   LEFT JOIN pans p
   ON f.fact_id = pafact_id

   LEFT JOIN stas s
   ON f.fact_id = safact_id

   LEFT JOIN zelycs z
   ON f.fact_id = zafact_id
GROUP BY
   p.name,
   s.name,
   z.name
```

Comment: thanks a lot.... but when implementing it i had to change the p.name, s.name and z.name because the name column exists in the fact table and it displayed the result however in a weird way so thanks

Comment: i made it just name...the result displayed showed all the names of both pan, stas and zelyc and where it wasn't pan in the count aspect it displayed it as 0, where it was it displayed 1

Answer (score 1):

You could run each sub-query to find the one(s) returning multiple rows.

Alternatively, you could add '`where rownum = 1`' to each subquery, to force it to return only the first row it comes to.

Comment: (SELECT name FROM facts, Zelycs WHERE fact_id=zafact_id) AS NAMEOFZELYCS that is the one with multiple rows, the zelyc table contains multiple data

Comment: @GEILY -- OK -- so the way you're using the sub-queries (inside of the SELECT clause) requires that there only be 1 row returned.  So you need to decide how you're going to enforce that.  You could do it arbitrarily (per my answer above using rownum); otherwise, you'll need a stricter WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Queries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ...
```

will always return 1 rows, so they are fine.

You have 3 'details' tables pans, stas and zelyc
In one of them you have more than one row for fact_id.
Here is a query to find all problematic fact_id's:

```
SELECT 'pans' tbl, pafact_id, count(*) FROM pans
group by pafact_id
having count(*) > 1
union all
SELECT 'stas' tbl, pafact_id, count(*) FROM stas
group by pafact_id
having count(*) > 1
union all
SELECT 'zelyc' tbl, pafact_id, count(*) FROM zelyc
group by pafact_id
having count(*) > 1
```

*so how can i count multiple columns from multiple tables returning multiple rows*

I am not following..
You can't return a dataset (more than one row/column) from a subquery between SELECT and FROM keywords. This subquery should be scalar and return only one value.

- show source
- show desired output
- describe a logic how you want to get from source to output (unless it obvious)

Comment: so how can i count multiple coumns from multiple tables returning multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting the data in all the tables altogether, i joined each table individually to its superclass to get the number of data and the names of the data

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(fact_id) As NUMBEROFPANS, 
   name  AS NAMEOFPANS 
FROM 
   facts, 
   pans 
WHERE 
   fact_id=pafact_id GROUP BY (name);
```

output:

```
 NUMBEROFPANS    NAMEOFPANS 

  1               Jade
  1               arrow
```

so i did the same for all tables